# SHA1 hash code comparing fails

Tags: c#

I have written two method called-`MakeHash` and `CompareHash` on my .NET Core application. Now with `MakeHash` I am able to successfully converting SHA1 code but the problem is the way I am trying to compare hash code is always returns false. That means the `CompareHash` method is unable to compare plain code and SHA1 codes. Can you tell me how I can fix `CompareHash` so it will able to compare between plain text and SHA1 hash code? What am I doing wrong in `CompareHash` method? Thanks in advance

```
public static string MakeHash(string str)
{  
    // generate a 128-bit salt using a secure PRNG
    byte[] salt = new byte[128 / 8];
    using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
    {
        rng.GetBytes(salt);
    }
    // derive a 256-bit subkey (use HMACSHA1 with 10,000 iterations)
    string hashed = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
        password: str,
        salt: salt,
        prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
        iterationCount: 10000,
        numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));
    return hashed;
}

public static bool CompareHash(string plainString, string hashString)
{
    if (MakeHash(plainString)==hashString)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: For comparing hashes you should not generate a new salt, but use the one stored with the hash.

Comment: Should i save salt as string or something like that? Whats the solution. And is there any best practice for password store and comparing?

Comment: Yes, in a database you would have a column for the hash, and another one for the salt. Whether you store the salt and hash as a base64 string or byte array doesn't really matter.

Comment: If you have an existing column in your db table with sufficient entropy, you could use it for the hash. It depends on what your threat model looks like; how important the data you are protecting is.

Comment: You don’t need an extra column for the salt as you can store both of them in the same column. If you store the has binary as Byte array just concatenate them. You can easily split both because hash and salt usually have constant length. If you store the hash in base64, concatenate the base64 of the hash with the base64 of the salt with a separator in between like`:` or any other character which is not part of the 64 base64 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you need some quick solution without storing salt on your database then you can give a try with the code below. This works for me. But this is highly recommended to use salt and match between them. Because it's about security you should be careful and put some more effort into it. My example is just to provide you an idea, not for production usage.

```
public static string MakeHash(string value)
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(
                System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value))
                );
        }


        public static bool CompareHash(string plainString, string hashString)
        {
            if (MakeHash(plainString) == hashString)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If this hash is a password hash or in general used for security relevant data, not using a key derivation function like OP had already done is a really bad advise. He could easily have stored the salt and hash together in the database without the need to change anything in the database.

Comment: I know this is not good idea. But just to provide him a information that is it is also possible to do without salt

Comment: But if he follows that advice - which his acceptance implies - he now has a much bigger problem than before.